# Xamarin.ios Azure Devops Build failed

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build my xamarin.ios project using Azure Devops VSTS. But, its failing with below error:`Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/xbuild failed with return code: 1`

I have added Install Certificate and Install an Apple provisioning profile task as attached in below screenshot number 1. Still I'm not able to build the project. I have noticed that when build tasks are running I can not see Install P12 certificate task in it.

[image: Certificate and provisioning profile added]

[image]

in the second image I can notice no certificate install task is visible. Is this might be the issue ? or something else.

Comment: Check the output, there should be a more detailed error message somewhere in there.

Comment: Check the expanded output of 'Build ...' task for more details. The certifcate-installation is at the start of the build ("pre-job: install an apple certificate")

Comment: @D.J. yeah, but same for provisioning profile task also...still its showing before build ios task.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by expanding the output. The issues was the wrong path for the solution file.